# How to send an object to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to send data from the client side (javascript) to the server (php) via ajax.
I have an object that looks like this:

```
sinfo={
            topic_title:title,
            topic_id: tid,
            section_name:section_name,
            section_id: fid,
            circuito: "fc",
            from_mid:mid,
            sito:site,
            st: st,
            tags:{"m4148305":{"post_id":987649,"from_id":1}}
        }
```

And I want to pass that object to the server.
The only way I know is using JQuery, so I tried something like that:

```
$.post(baseurl+"/server/?act=post",sinfo,function(e)
               {
            sessionStorage.PixelTagSystemTagRequest="false";
        });
```

And it works fine on Chrome and Safari. But Firefox displays an odd error, something like:

> calling event .click() on an HTMLElement which does
>   not implement the interface

The solution should be simple: update JQuery, unfortunately I'm not allowed to do so.
So I tried a Pure JS solution

```
var fd = new FormData(), lol, xml;
        for(lol in sinfo)
        {
            fd.append(lol,sinfo[lol]);
            //alert(lol+" = "+sinfo[lol]);
        }
        xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xml.open("POST",baseurl+"/server/?act=post");
        xml.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(xml.readyState==4)
            {
                sessionStorage.PixelTagSystemTagRequest="false";
                alert(xml.responseText);
            }
        };
        xml.send(fd);
```

But the *sinfo.tags* is still an object and I do not know how to pass that property to the server.

P.s: I'm trying to avoid to stringify the object (in JSON), so i don't have to change the php code.

Comment: Is there a particular limiting factor why you can't change the PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use FormData, you can add some code like:

```
for(lol in sinfo)
{
    if (lol == "tags") {
        for (lok in sinfo[lol]) {
            fd.append("tags[" + lok + "]", sinfo[lol][lok];
        }
    } else {
        fd.append(lol,sinfo[lol]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Reading the question would've done. *`"P.s: I'm trying to avoid to stringify the object (in JSON), so i don't have to change the php code."`*

Comment: All right, I delete the JSON3, please use that code. It will be work in FormData.